# Filtering and reducing lazy structures

Tags: swift, generics, lazy-evaluation, lazy-sequences

I would like to `filter` a lazy structure and then `reduce` it using Swift language.

```swift
func main() -> () {
    let result = (1...)
        .lazy
        .filter { $0 < 3 }
        .reduce(0, {$0 + $1})
    return print(
        result
    )
}

main()
```

This code compiles; however, the program doesn't execute in a proper way (takes too long). The printed result on the screen should be `3`.
Is there a way to accomplish this goal ?

Comment: `(1...)` it is not an array

Comment: You're right. Correcting it.

Comment: Thanks for asking, @Leo Dabus. I'm trying to understand how can I `reduce` a lazy structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not that your sequence is lazy, it's that your sequence is infinite. You might be looking for the `sequence` method. Example:

```
let s = sequence(first: 0) {
    $0 > 3 ? nil : $0 + 1
}
let result = s.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }
print(result) // 10
```

`s` is `lazy` and is *potentially* infinite but not *actually* infinite, because the method that generates the next item in the series does an early exit by returning `nil` when the sequence goes past 3. This is similar to your `filter` except that it is not a filter, it's a stopper. You can use any condition you like here to generate the stopper.

Comment: or a regular for loop with a break. `for x in 1... {` `if x < 3 {` `result += 1` `} else {` `break` `}` `}`

Comment: Thank you so much, @matt ! I understood the concept. By the way, I bought you book "AppleScript: The Definitive Guide" a while ago and learned a lot :-)

Comment: Well _that_ brings back memories! :)

Answer (score 0):

To get the program to terminate, you would need to add an upper limit on your original sequence `(1...)`.

As it's written, you have an infinite sequence of numbers, starting at `1`. The following operators — the `filter`, in particular — have no way of "knowing" that they can discard the rest of the sequence once they pass `3`. They have to process the *entire infinite sequence*, filtering out all but the first two elements, before your `reduce` can produce a final result and you can print it out. (In practice, you'll eventually overflow Int, so the program would terminate then, but that's not really a good thing to rely on.)

If you don't want to change the original `(1...)`, you can approximate the same behavior by swapping out your `filter` with a `prefix`. A filter has to look at every element; a prefix can "know" that it stops after a certain number of elements. For example, this runs very quickly and prints out `3`:

```
let result = (1...)
    .lazy
    .prefix(2)
    .reduce(0) {$0 + $1}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Tim. So, there is no way to reduce a lazy structure ? The problem is: I do not know beforehand how many elements will remain after the filter.

Comment: @F.Zer And neither does the compiler and neither does the runtime. This has nothing to do with the fact that the sequence is lazy; it has to do with the fact the sequence is infinite. It's totally unclear what the goal is supposed to be here.